# How to turn off MSI in KVM's PCI Passthrough?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

In ESXi VM, you can disable MSI in PCI Passthrough with

```
pciPassthru.msiEnabled = FALSE
```

How to do it in `virt-manager` XML for a VM with QEMU/KVM?

Comment: Probably best to ask on [su]. It's off-topic here.